# Laravel 4.2 Page Views Counter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So i added this page view counter to my app that counts each visit on a artist page. Right now if you refresh the page the counter is +1 each refresh.

My question is how can i make it to count unique visits by day only?

My Controller:

```
        if ( $artist ) {

        $getartist   = $this->_artist->get($artist, 'slug');

        if ( $getartist ) {

            $getsongs = $this->_song->collections($input, $getartist->id, 'ASC');
            $this->_artist->updateVisits($getartist->id);
            $data = [
                        'is_artist'   => true,
                        'artist'      => $getartist,
                        'songs'       => $getsongs,
                        'randomsongs' => $this->randomsongs,
                    ];
            return $this->view('index', $data);

        }

    }
```

The code for counter is:

```
$this->_artist->updateVisits($getartist->id);
```

Then in my ArtistRepository:

```
public function updateVisits($artist_id)
{
$artist = $this->model->where("id",$artist_id)->first();
$artist->visits = $artist->visits+1;
$artist->save();
}
```

So how do i prevent counter from counting if user refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

First add a `date` field on `DB table`. Then change your function to following-

```
public function updateVisits($artist_id)
{
   $artist = $this->model->firstOrCreate(['id' => $artist_id,'your_date_field_name'=>date('Y-m-d')]);
   $artist->visits = $artist->visits+1;
   $artist->save();
}
```

And don't forget to add `id, your_date_field_name` on `fillable` array to be `mass` assignable.

Comment: "And don't forget to add id, your_date_field_name on fillable array to be mass assignable." I did not understand this. I test your solution as it is and is creating new empty fields in my db each visit. Also hows that will count unique visits? i dont get it how it resets and how it knows that im new visitor?

Comment: In your eloquent model class, there is a fillable array. add id, another_field there

Comment: protected $fillable = [ 'id','your_date_field_name'];

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution around this with cookies
Heres my code.

```
public function updateVisits($artist_id)
{
$artist = $this->model->where("id",$artist_id)->first();

// Check if cookies exist
if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited_id' . $artist_id])) {
// If not set cookie and pass counter
setcookie('visited_id' . $artist_id, $artist_id, time()+30);  /* expire in seconds */
$artist->visits = $artist->visits+1;
$artist->save();

// If cookie exist on user computer
} else {
//do nothing
}
}
```